# split each item of array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array like this

```
array = ["My Name", "1905", "more than three words"]
```

What I would like to do is split each item of the array by its space and then create 1 array with each word, so

```
["My", "Name", "1905", "more", "than", "three", "words"]
```

What I have tried so far is

```
words = []
array.each do { |a| words << a.to_s.split(" ") }
```

This returns

```
[["My", "Name"], ["1905"], ["more", "than", "three", "words"]]
```

But I have multiple arrays within an array. How would I go about achieving

```
["My", "Name", "1905", "more", "than", "three", "words"]
```

I'm missing something obvious aren't I?

Comment: simply flatten the array, see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
array.join(' ').split(' ')
```

Example:

```
["My Name", "1905", "more than three words"].join(' ').split(' ') # => ["My", "Name", "1905", "more", "than", "three", "words"]
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to flatten it, or do flatten while mapping.

```
array.flat_map{|e| e.split(" ")}
```

You can also do this:

```
array.inject([]){|a, s| a + s.split(" ")}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the output that you want.

```
array.join(" ").split
```

Alternative using `scan`:

```
array.join(" ").scan(/\S+/)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.collect { |a| a.split(" ") }.flatten 
#=> ["My", "Name", "1905", "more", "than", "three", "words"]
```